# PHP how to reference neighbor class with $this->classname?

Tags: php, reference, extends

There is clearly I miss something. I have the following code:

```
<?php

class module {
    protected $registry;
    public $controller;
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $var = 'global';

}

class controller extends module {
    public function test_controller() {
        echo 'controller test';
        echo $this->var;
        $this->model->test_model();
        $this->view->test_view();
    }
}

class model extends module {
    public function test_model() {
        echo 'model test';
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class view extends module {
    public function test_view() {
        echo 'view test';
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$module = new module();
$module->controller = new controller();
$module->model = new model();
$module->view = new view();

echo "\n\n\n" . print_r($module);

$module->controller->test_controller();
```

And at the end I get "Call to a member function test_model() on null". I do understand that variables of class 'module' are being re-initialized each time the 'extender' class is being instantiated. Ok, no problem, but I assign 'parent' class property with needed 'value' right after that (I mean $module->controller = new controller();).

I do not understand how to deal with this behavior. I'd like to achieve this type of referencing inside a module that I've wrote in controller function: $this->model->some_func(), $this->view->some_other(). There also will be a so called registry with other classes that also should be available for extended classes.

If this is a design issue - well, please, point me :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you extend the module class?

Comment: The controller's instance has a null model, and view.

Comment: If you really want to share variables across difference instances of inherited classes, you can use a static property, and you'll need to reference them differently.  But this is likely an anti-pattern.

Comment: I extend module class because the functionality in $registry should be available to controller, model, view classes. This is one thing. And another one is that I'd like to reference model and another classes from controller (and another classes) like $this->model, $this->api, $this->controller etc.

Answer (score 0):

These are different instances.  Same as below:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public $bar;
    public $baz;
}

class Baz extends Foo
{
    public function showMeTheBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$foo      = new Foo;
$foo->bar = 'Hat';
$foo->baz = new Baz;
var_dump($foo->baz->showMeTheBar());
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

`$foo`'s bar and `$foo::baz`'s bar are not one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other answer(s), the controller has ownership of the `$this->model` and the `$this->view` so in your instance, you have to assign the controller the new instances:

```
$module = new module();
$module->controller         =   new controller();
# Need to assign to the controller now, not the $module
$module->controller->model  =   new model();
$module->controller->view   =   new view();
```

This is probably what you are not intending to do. If you want to do what you are doing, you have to do it in the `$module` scope and bring the single elements back into `module`:

```
<?php
class module
{
    public $controller,
           $model,
           $view;

    public $var = 'global';

    protected $registry;
    # Add a new method that basically does what your controller method was doing.
    # Difference is that now these other classes are in the $module scope
    public function get()
    {
        $this->controller->test_controller();
        $this->model->test_model();
        $this->view->test_view();
    }
}

class controller extends module
{
    public function test_controller()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class model extends module {
    public function test_model()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class view extends module {
    public function test_view()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$module = new module();
$module->model = new model();
$module->view = new view();
$module->controller = new controller();
$model->get();
```

You may want to use injection though I am not sure how many classes you are intending to assign:

```
$module = new module(new model(), new view(), new controller());
$module->view->test_view();
```

If you inject and want to use dynamic injection, you may want to look at Reflection so your classes don't need explicit param assignment.

You could move into the range of dynamic calling, but if you aren't careful, that could get into a bit of a rabbit hole!

```
<?php
class module
{
    public $var = 'global';
    protected $registry;
    # Might want to add a getter
    public function __get($prop)
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $prop)) {
            return $this->{$prop};
        }
    }
    # Create a method getter
    public function __call($class, $args = false)
    {
        $class = strtolower(str_replace('get','', $class));
        # Set the dynamic variable
        if(!isset($this->{$class}))
            $this->{$class} = (is_array($args))? new $class(...$args) : new $class($args);
        # Send back new variable
        return $this->{$class};
    }
}

class controller extends module
{
    public function test_controller()
    {
         echo $this->var;
    }
}

class model extends module
{
    public function test_model()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class view extends module
{
    public  function __construct()
    {
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }

    public function test_view()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

# Create instance of module
$module =   new module();
# use getView() to fetch and assign view
print_r($module->getView('arg1', 'arg2')->test_view());
# Since you set this value already, it can be pulled directly or by using
# getView()
print_r($module->view);
```

What you get from this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => arg1
    [1] => arg2
)

global

view Object
(
    [var] => global
    [registry:protected] => 
)
```

Dynamic calling has it's place, so if you employ it, just do it mindfully.

For persistant variables, as mentioned you could use a static variable so if you change the variable in one class it changes in all.

Comment: Yes, exactly: I had to assign manually those instances to each needed class. This way I have more control of who sees who. As for the 'getter' (__get) - I've also had to rethink this, because the getter is already defined to fit $registry. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The state of `$module` before calling `Controller::test_controller()` as a tree (I'll show class names in a camel-case manner):

```
$module: Module
Props:
  $controller: Controller
  Props:
    $controller: null
    $model: null
    $view: null
    $var: "global"
  $model: Model
  Props:
    $controller: null
    $model: null
    $view: null
    $var: "global"
  $view: View
  Props:
    $controller: null
    $model: null
    $view: null
    $var: "global"
  $var: "global"
```

Can you see? `$module->controller` is different from `$module->controller->controller`. Even `$module->var` and `$module->controller->var` are not the same thing. `$module` and `$module->controller` are different.

I don't know if you're doing the right thing, but the solution would be using dependency injection; which means you should pass (inject) `$module` (dependency) as an argument to `Controller::test_controller()` or whatever it is.

Comment: Yep, I've realized that. Thanks for answer. I had to rethink this stuff about 'visibility' of the classes, for example view must be available for controller, but controller must not be available to view, etc. I've redesigned this structure.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. That is how it happens: you have to ask to find answer yourself :)

The points of entry to the app are controller and api, so I have to make stuff available there, but not elsewhere: 'view' must not see 'model'.

So in case if anyone might be looking for this design - there it is:

```
$controller = new Controller($registry);
$model = new Model($registry);
$api = new Api($registry);
$view = new Template($modulename);
//these classes above are already extended by abstract classes to bring $registry classes with __get()

$settings = new Settings($modulename);
$language = new Language($code);

$module = new stdClass();

$module->controller = $controller;
$module->controller->model = $model;
$module->controller->view = $view;
$module->controller->api = $api; //this might be questionable, but sometimes it's easier to do so
$module->controller->settings = $settings;
$module->controller->language = $language;

$module->api = $api;
$module->api->model = $model;
$module->api->view = $view;
$module->api->controller = $controller; //this might also be questionable, but sometimes it's easier to do so
$module->api->settings = $settings;
$module->api->language = $language; 

$model->settings = $settings;
```

The goal was to make calls (in controller and api) like `$this->model->method(), $this->view->method()`, etc., which I've managed to achieve.